# Hadoop HA Namenode loggin "WARN : All existing blocks are COMPLETE, lease removed .. "

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have create a setup of Highly Available Hadoop Namenodes with 2 namenodes Using Qourom Journal Manager and ZooKeeper. there are two datanodes added to the hdfs also. Now what i wanted to do is to keep 2 replica of each file on each node so configured the namenode accordingly.

After the setup, to test i created a script that continuously pumps files to hdfs. After insertion of few hundred files, few warning logs are getting logged.

```
2017-06-20 18:11:41,373 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseManager: [Lease.  Holder: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1898985663_95936, pending creates: 1] has expired hard limit
2017-06-20 18:11:41,376 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Recovering [Lease.  Holder: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1898985663_95936, pending creates: 1], src=/user/hadoop/1906201706/6206c29f-a8f7-4315-bc39-6763e88a2240
2017-06-20 18:11:41,377 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* internalReleaseLease: All existing blocks are COMPLETE, lease removed, file /user/hadoop/1906201706/6206c29f-a8f7-4315-bc39-6763e88a2240 closed.
```

Need help on these warning messeges. What does these logs means?